# tf command line recursivly find all the labels

Tags: tfs

How do I search all the labels I have applied? I applied different labels on a folder or some files. I have tried to find the msdn article here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t21wc9ca(v=vs.100).aspx

but there's no direction to do that. Any one help?

Answer (score 0):

Files don't *have* labels.  Labels *contain* files.

You'll need to use the [`tf labels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t21wc9ca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) command to inspect the labels you've created, looking for the files you want to match.